# I'm being attacked by a Click Robot cycling addresses

Tags: discussion, badges

Just got 1000 clicks in one hour:

[image: click bot2.png]

---

I hardly get badges, but on U&L tonight, in an hour, a robot is creating like six of them. I appreciate the new hat but it is distracting:

[image: click bot.png]

To make matters worse, whilst typing this question I got a "yearling" badge which might really be valid.

What's going on?

Comment: Oh I do appreciate the new hat though. If you take back the badges can I still keep the hat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happened to a number of people.

Regarding the "Announcer" badge:  A bug was fixed.  See [Suddenly getting "Announcer" badges every few minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340292/suddenly-getting-announcer-badges-every-few-minutes) (and then [Missing publicist badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339664/missing-publicist-badge)) on the main Meta site. You can't give badges back.

Regarding the hats: No, you can't unfortunately keep the hats that you earn in the "Winter Bash" past January 1. See the [Winter bash 2019 FAQ](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/faq).

The above also addresses [your comment](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/im-being-attacked-by-a-click-robot-cycling-addresses#comment10595_5465).

Comment: One small correction, the 7 badges were gone this morning.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The badges could have been given to you, then deleted, during the bug fixing that StackExchange were doing. What I meant was that you can't give back badges that you gain ordinarily. If you were never _supposed_ to have those badges, then they were obviously given due to some mishap, which was later corrected.